# Google Play Services Locatio API / setSmallestDisplacement not working

Tags: android, location

I'm creating a vehicle tracking system, which get's the location from Google Play Services Location API. I've set the update interval to 5 seconds which provides good results when the car is moving. To avoid getting updates close to each other for example when the vehicle is stopped at traffic lights, I've set the setSmallestDisplacement(int meters) to 50m. 
My understanding of this would be that I should get updates every 5 seconds, **IF the location has changed at least 50m.** But this doesn't seem to be the case, as I get them still almost every 5 seconds with the locations being just few meters apart (this due to the normal GPS drift).

The question is, have I understood the effect of setSmallestDisplacement() wrong, or is it not working as it should?

Relevant code:

```
private LocationRequest request;
private LocationClient client;
request = LocationRequest.create();
request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
request.setInterval(5000);
request.setFastestInterval(1000);
request.setSmallestDisplacement(50);
client = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
if (servicesConnected())
    client.connect();


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
    try {
        gpsConnected = true;
        client.requestLocationUpdates(request, this);
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to Google Play Services");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnected", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: requestLocationUpdates is truly buggy. Dont expect it to work. Its connected to teh cache of google maps and not to actually go and get something from the web. Try this, instead load google maps app and run your app side by side, it will work really well. Else it wont. If this happens, let me know I have a fix for it.

Comment: Seems so. I removed the Google Location services and use the Android LocationManager instead. Downside is that I won't get as good results in poor GPS coverage, but the upside is that it works!

Comment: Keep in mind that GPS.Provider will take on a lot of battery, and heat up the device if you run it long. If you use the NEtworkProvider you need to hack you way through.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. But since the main use for the App will be tracking vehicles, battery usage won't be an issue when the car is running. And for times the car is stopped and power is off (=no charging) I will only poll the GPS using AlarmManager every now and then.

Comment: What are you building ? I have something similar taxeeta on the android play store.

Comment: Funny. my app worked perfectly well until recently.
Suddenly the displacement stopped working and it updates as fast as it can with the same coordinates.
Quite a shame for Google to release it like that.

On top of it: Expect your clients IP to be blocked by Google if you update every 3 seconds for a longer while.
In my case it takes about half an hour and my IP is blocked, although I set smallestdisplacement. So the bug is quite a showstopper.

Comment: have you tried to remove request.setInterval(5000); ?